# Run AT command using PHP exec()

Tags: php, 19.04

I have to schedule a few tasks to run only once in the near future. For that i'm intending to use the `at` command. I want to schedule those tasks using `exec()`(or any other recommended method).

But i'm stuck. Trough `putty` i can manually schedule tasks this way:

```
user@ubuntu:~# at 09:00am Jul 15 [enter]
at> php /path/to/script.php [ctrl+d]
```

But i can't figure out a way to do it trough php. Help:-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in the command you use to execute:

```
echo "php /path/to/script.php" | at 09:00am Jul 15
```

I don't use PHP but it [looks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) like it then needs to be

```
exec('echo "php /path/to/script.php" | at 09:00am Jul 15')
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! :D